# Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: csv, d3.js, nan

I'm trying to make a bar graph using data downloaded from the WHO site, into an Excel doc. My .csv is as so (have tried both with and without the "s)

```
"WHO_region","percentage"
"Africa",52.2
"Americas",83
"South-East Asia",75.1
"Europe",75.1
"Eastern Mediterranean",63.6
"Western Pacific",89.7
```

I'm trying to use the percentage column to determine the height of my bars, I've pulled "percent" out to be its own variable whilst I play around with it as it's a bit cleaner? Nothing is working - not parseFloat, parseInt, etc? Why may this be? Full code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //declare global variables 
    var w = 600, h = 200, padding = 30, margin = 30;

    //import the .csv data
    d3.csv("WHO_familyplanningdata.csv", function(data) {
            console.log(data)});

    //create the SVG
    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

    //import the .csv data
    d3.csv("WHO_familyplanningdata.csv", function(data) {
            console.log(data); 

    //clean up data
    var percent = parseInt(data.percentage)

    //create rects, and add them to the SVG 
    svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d,i) {
                    return i * (w / data.length);
            }) //distributes them across the x axis 
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", (w / data.length) /2)
            .attr("height", function(d, i) { 
                    return percent;
            });

 }); //end of the data wrapping 
   </script>
```

Any help is really appreciated - thank you! :)

Comment: When you pass an anonymous function with a variable `d` as an argument, you should use that variable as an alias in the body of the function: `d.percent`

Comment: have a look at your `percent` variable it probably is `undefined` because an array does not have a `percentage` field. The way you use the `data` is incorrect. Look at the Blocks examples. You need to convert the string to a percentage number.

Comment: Thank you both - I've managed to get it to work: 

                .attr("height", function(d, i) {
                        return +d.percentage;
                });
Pretty sure I did this earlier - but for some reason, is functioning now!